# Organize code in javascript Dojo working with XHR, REST

Tags: javascript, class, rest, dojo, dao

I am trying to organize my code in Dojo but I, do not understanding how things work. I want to catch the json data after a REST call but it isn't working.  The *testJson* property, which I'm assigning REST return to, is always NULL.

How can I do this? I've copied my current code below. (I want to use my code in a ClassDAO and Controller.

```
define([
    'dojo/_base/declare',
    'dojo/request/xhr'
], function (declare, xhr) {

    return declare(null, {


        testJson: null,

        constructor: function(){

        },

        get: function(){

            xhr('/rest/reports', {
                method: 'get',
                handleAs: 'json',
                headers: {
                    Accept: 'application/json'
                }

            }).then(function(jsonData){

                    testJson = jsonData;

                }, function(err){
                    alert(err);
                }, function(evt){
                    // Handle a progress event from the request if the
                    // browser supports XHR2
                });

        }

    });
});
```

Comment: I found it difficult to understand what you were saying. I don't know if you could get someone who speaks English as a first language to proof read your questions before posting? Sorry for being rude, just it makes it very difficult to understand what you are asking.  In this case I think I figured it out from your code.

More importantly the questions and answers here are meant to be a resource for other people.  Without clear English it is difficult for this goal to be achieved.

Comment: Sorry my english, but I am trying to improve it.

Comment: Resume: I need put jsonData to testJson(property). I thought my question was easy for to understand. Sorry again.

Comment: I'm really just trying to be helpful, rather than being critical.  Most of my family lives overseas and do not speak English as a first language and I have close friends from a number of European countries.  That is why I decided to decipher your question as I understand the barriers.  My suggestion is to get a proof-reader before posting question (if possible).  Your question was not clear at-all, more like machine translated text and that will put others off answering you and encourage downvotes.  Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to set a class property as a variable; hence,

```
testJson = jsonData;
```

ought to be:

```
this.testJson = jsonData
```

Otherwise you are actually setting the global variable testJson, instead of a property.  You also need to scope your **then()** function to your class:

```
.then(lang.hitch(this, function(jsonData){
    this.testJson = jsonData;
}))
```

The *lang* object is *dojo/_base/lang* and needs adding to the **define()**

```
define([
    "dojo/_base/declare",
    "dojo/request/xhr",
    "dojo/_base/lang"
], function (declare, xhr, lang) {
```

Scoping is an important concept of Javascript that has tripped us all up in the past. See the documentation for the [**hitch()**](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojo/_base/lang.html#dojo-base-lang-hitch) command for more details.

Comment: My intention was a property. I tryed before with THIS, but it does not work, as well. But your information is really useful. I will try it and after I go back for to say the result.

Comment: I tried your example and others examples on the link, but didn't work yet.

Comment: Are you waiting till the Json has been loaded before accessing testJson.  testJson will remain as null until the data is loaded as it running asynchronously.  Try putting a console.log in your then() function to see if it is actually loading the data.

Comment: You are right. I have changed to sync:true and now works fine. Thanks.